# SQL Query for getting the movie id and number of people of each gender for that movie ID

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I have a database that contains the following tables:
[image: Database Schema]

I have to write an SQL query that can give the number of actors for each gender in every movie in that database in separate rows. The answer has to look like this:

[image: Answer format]

That is, I want separate rows for each gender for each movie.
I am very new to SQL and can't seem to get any ideas about how to start writing the query.
How do I go about doing this?
Thank You.

**EDIT:**
The M_Cast table contains too many rows and joining anything with the M_Cast table takes a lot of time to complete.
Thankfully, I was able to figure out the answer without using any Joins and the query is much faster.

Here is my answer for anyone who wants to refer to it:

```
With
MA_Pair AS
(
Select TRIM(MID) MID, TRIM(PID) PID From M_Cast
Group By MID, PID
)
Select map.MID, p.Gender, Count(*) From Person p, MA_Pair map
Where TRIM(p.PID)=map.PID
Group By map.MID, p.Gender
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Does the table Person contain `None` in the column `Gender`, or is it NULL?

Comment: As I said I am very new to SQL and thus I have no idea on how to even start thinking about a 'quick enough' solution.

Comment: @forpas there are some entires in the gender column with a None value

Comment: Do you always want a row with None for a movie, even if there are no actors with None as Gender?

Comment: @forpas no no, I only want None for the movies that have a gender entry of an actor as none.

Answer (score 2):

For this requirement you need to join only 2 tables: `Person` and `M_Cast`.

```
SELECT c.MID, p.Gender, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM M_Cast c INNER JOIN Person p
ON p.PID = c.PID
GROUP BY c.MID, p.Gender
```

You may add an `ORDER BY` clause to sort conditionally the rows:

```
ORDER BY p.Gender = 'None' DESC,
         p.Gender = 'Female' DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `m_cast` to join between `movie` and `person`, and then group by the `mid` and `gender`:

```sql
SELECT   m.mid, gender, COUNT(*)
FROM     movie m
JOIN     m_cast c ON m.mid = c.mid
JOIN     person p ON c.pid = p.pid
GROUP BY m.mid, gender
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the table M_Cast is very big with some hundred thousand rows and thus joining on it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If for someone it is giving empty data frame use TRIM for M_Cast.

```
SELECT trim(c.MID),p.Gender,COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN M_Cast c
ON p.PID=trim(c.PID)
GROUP BY trim(c.MID), p.Gender
```